# Search String from Arraylist Android

Tags: java, android

I am working with google maps api v2. In my project i have used Clickable listview.I wanted to Implement search in My listview.My main obk=jective is to implement search in the listview.
this is my code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

       listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        if (getMumbai().size() > 0){
            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listview_item,getMumbai());
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        }

    }


    private ArrayList<Mumbai> getMumbai(){
        ArrayList<Mumbai> Mumbai = new ArrayList<>();
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("dadar","18.990622", "72.836590",R.drawable.icon1,"1"));
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("Dongri","18.960386", "72.839130",R.drawable.icon2,"2"));
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("Matunga ","19.0480255", "72.8659563",R.drawable.icon3,"3"));
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("Matunga dadar","19.0481083", "72.8331249",R.drawable.icon4,"4"));
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("parel","19.176402", "72.950076",R.drawable.icon5,"5"));
        Mumbai.add(new Mumbai("Mulund","19.180155", "72.947571",R.drawable.icon6,"6"));
        return  Mumbai;

    }
      }
```

this is my adapter1:-

```
public class Mumbai {
    private String name;
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    private String numberlv;
    private int imglist;

    public Mumbai(String name, String lat, String lng,int imglist,String numberlv) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.numberlv = numberlv;
        this.imglist=imglist;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public int getImglist(){ return imglist;}

    public void setImglist(int imglist){this.imglist=imglist;}

    public String getNumberlv() {
        return numberlv;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.numberlv = numberlv;
    }
}
```

I know my code is mess but a help would be appreciated a lot .

Comment: "didn't got success"  Is not a question. Please [edit] to describe the problem in words

Comment: What is your issue? If you want implement search functionality,  take one edittext with addOnTextChangeListener. So, while you entering the each letter, you can search with in arraylist and based on that filter data..

Answer (score 0):

You set the click listener on the `ListView`, not within the adapter.

```
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
```

Also, extract `getMumbai()` to a `final ArrayList` variable so you can use `list.get(position)` within that click method